# Abraham's Twitter oAuth PHP Library - Store user access tokens in WordPress database?

Tags: wordpress, oauth

I am using Abraham's Twitter OAuth PHP Library and it is a very good starter. I am working on WordPress and I want to know how i can store the access tokens in the user table of my WordPress database instead of the sessions so that it is persistent and users can quickly do stuff.

http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) to save and [get_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to set custom values for users.

Comment: Awesome and Thank you so much for the library that saved a lot of time for many developers.

Comment: It seemed simple but i am struggling.